# Matlab GUI spreadsheet I/O

Tags: excel, matlab, import, io, spreadsheet

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?
Im able to import a Excel File into my Matlab GUI, the problem is the file exist in a few sheets combined together (example: monthly data). I'm trying to import the data from different sheets on the excel file but was not able to (anything from the 2nd sheet i can't import). Anyone knows of a code to import the data?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement as well as the code in use — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used xlsread in order to read data from an XLS file. If you do not add arguments to the function, it will only read the first worksheet. Please check the xlsread documentation by typing doc xlsread in your matlab session.

You can see that you can specify the worksheet with the following code :

```
num = xlsread(filename,sheet)
```